# Normalization of a plane curve (showing equality of ideals)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm computing the normalization of the curve $y^3-x^4-x^3$ in $k[x,y]$, where $k$ is a field, and I'm only missing one key step. I want to show that the kernel of the map
$$
f:k[x,y]\to k[x,y,t]/(xt-y,t^3-x-1)\cong k[t]
$$
is precisely the ideal defined by the curve. It's clear that $(y^3-x^4-x^3)\subseteq\ker f$, yet I can't show the other contention. In case it's useful the map into $k[t]$ is given by $x\mapsto t^3-1$ and $y\mapsto t(t^3-1)$.

I've tried messing with the polynomials with no success. It seems to be one of those problem where there is a method that works more generally, so if it's the case I'd appreciate an explanation. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial $y^3-x^3(x+1)$ is irreducible (Eisenstein), therefore it generates a prime ideal $P$ of $k[x,y]$. $P$ is not maximal, because it is properly contained in the prime ideal $(x,y)$. The image of the map $f$ is a domain, hence its kernel $Q$ must be a prime ideal. Since $P\subseteq Q$ and $k[x,y]$ has Krull dimension $2$ either $P=Q$ or $Q$ is maximal. But in the latter case $k[x,y]/Q$ is a field contained in $k[t]$, hence equal to $k$. Consequently $f(x)=t^3-1\in k$, which is wrong.

Comment: Hi Hagen, thanks for the great answer. I'm just a bit confused about the second to last claim. If $k[x,y]/Q$ is a field contained in $k[t]$ I don't see how this implies it is equal to $k$ or even just contained in $k$. Could we instead argue that "$t^2-1\in k[x,y]/Q$, so it is an invertible element, which is impossible by degree reasons"?

Comment: For every proper ideal $I$ of $k[x,y]$ the equation $I\cap k=0$ holds. Thus always $k\subseteq k[x,y]/I$. In the case $I=Q$ one gets $k\subseteq K/Q\subseteq k[t]$. Now you argument with the degree reasons shows that $K/Q=k$.