# Integral extension of rings $K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)\subset K[z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Prove that there is an integral inclusion $\phi:K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)\to K[z]$

I'm trying to use $\phi([x])=z^2-1$ and $\phi([y])=z(z^2-1)$. That way, $z$ is integral over $K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$, because $z^3-z-\phi([y])=z^3-z-z(z^2-1)=0$, therefore $K[z]$ is also integral. That way, $\phi$ is an integral morphism.

Now I'm left to prove that $\phi$ is injective, but I'm having a lot of difficulty with that.

Does this choice of $\phi$ work? If so, how do I prove that $\ker(\phi)=0$? Thanks!

Comment: What about passing to the respective quotient fields.  Since the map is obviously not the zero map and it's between fields, it must be injective.

Comment: The answer to this question may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212770/normalization-of-a-plane-curve-showing-equality-of-ideals

Comment: @sharding4, in order to pass to the quotient fields, I need to prove that denominators $\overline {1}/\overline{p(x,y)}$ are not sent to $\overline{1}/\overline {0}$ (otherwise, the field homomorphism is not defined). Isn't it equivalent to proving that $\ker (\phi)=0$?

Comment: @AguirreK You are absolutely right. A map of domains induces a map of quotient fields iff it is injective. I couldn't grasp the sense of this comment either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$ is a **one**-dimensional domain. A map from a one-dimensional domain to another domain is always injective if the image is not a field. Clearly the image is not a field, because it contains $z^2-1$, which is not invertible in $K[z]$.